# Multiple columns in when case in sql

Tags: sql

```
SELECT ...
    CASE
        WHEN BONUS = 400 then SALARY = SALARY+400
    END
From Emp;
```

While im using `=` for salary column I'm getting syntax error.

Comment: Do you want to display Salary+400 in output of select query or you want to update records in table ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add bonus to salary and show the result, then remove the `salary=` inside the case statement.

```
SELECT ...
    CASE WHEN BONUS = 400 then SALARY+400 END as SALARY 
From Emp;
```

Comment: Actually my requirement is to use '=' to operator.

Comment: @chaitu - What is use of `=` operator here ?

Comment: here i gave a small example. My requirement is
when column1 = 'xyz' then column2 = 'abc' (This is my requirement)

Comment: @chaitu - Still not clear. Add sample data and expected result in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
SELECT 
    SALARY = CASE
               WHEN BONUS = 400 then SALARY+400
             END
 From Emp;
```

OR

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN BONUS = '400' 
    then SALARY +400 
END
From Emp;
```

IF you want to update new salary then use.

```
UPDATE Emp
SET SALARY = SALARY + CASE WHEN BONUS =400 THEN 400 ELSE 0  END;
```

Comment: Actually my requirement is to use '=' to operator.

Comment: @chaitu.. Means ? Explain with sample result and table structure with expected result

Comment: My requirement is when column1 = 'xyz' then column2 = 'abc'

Comment: @chaitu check updated code

Answer (score 0):

In a select statement, the CASE expression works very similar to a function.

In your case, It will return a single value and not two columns.

If you require: to return two columns, column1 (BONUS) and column2 (SALARY) and salary depends on the bonus, you could consider something like this.

```
SELECT 
    -- Column1
    BONUS, -- Column BONUS from Emp table
    -- Column2
    CASE 
       WHEN BONUS = 400 THEN SALARY+400
       ELSE SALARY
    END AS SALARY -- 'SALARY' alias is assigned to the resultant value of the CASE (to make this a named Column)
FROM Emp
```

you will have a result set with two columns BONUS and SALARY in which the SALARY value depends on the value of the BONUS column.